# Conserved quantities in a resonant cavity

Tags: electromagnetism, noethers-theorem

In electromagnetism courses, it is a standard exercise to calculate eigenmodes and eigenfrequencies of a perfectly conducting resonant cavity. Typically cuboidal, cylindrical or spherical cavities are used, because in those cases analytical solutions exist.

Let $\vec{E}_i=\vec{f}_i(x,y,z)\exp(i\omega_i t)$ be the $i$th eigenmode of such a cavity. Then the electric field can be written
$$\vec{E}=\sum_i \alpha_i \vec{E}_i=\sum_i \alpha_i \vec{f}_i(x,y,z)\exp(i\omega_i t)$$
where $\alpha_i$ is the amplitude for the $i$th eigenmode.

It occurs to me that $|\alpha_i\exp(i\omega_i t)|=|\alpha_i|$ is time-invariant: the physics in the cavity has an infinite number of conserved quantities, the norms of the amplitudes of the eigenmodes.

> **Question (1)** Can Noether's theorem be used in reverse here? Does the existence of an infinite number of conserved quantities imply the existence of an an infinite number of continuous symmetries, and if so what are they?
>
> **Question (2)** Can the constancy of the eigenmode amplitudes be used to show that the total energy in the cavity is conserved? Is there any connection between the two?